# objective-c delegation

Tags: objective-c, ios, sockets, gcdasyncsocket

im new to iOS and objective-c, but im trying to use [GCDAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) 
I'm using it to contact TCP/IP server for the whole application,
in each viewController i want to start sending and receiving from/to server, so each time i alloc new instance of cocaSocket, and it send to the server like im new client.

so how can i make sure that one instance of cocaSocket could be applied to the whole application.

thanks for any response !

Comment: You probably need Singleton pattern, but I am not sure whether it is applicable here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you might create the Socket in your AppDelegate and store it in a property.

```
 // pseudo code - did not check the documentation how to actually create such a beast
 self.socket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc] init];
```

Then in other classes, you may access the app delegate via

```
(myAppDelegate *) [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] socket];
```

I don't think you'll need a singleton here.

Comment: +1 Technically it *is* a singleton since it is a property on an object that is itself a singleton :)  But it's a much better solution IMO than mucking about creating your own singletons.

Comment: i'll try it and let you know !